# What is the wisdom behind hiding adultery between spouses?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, adultery

What is the wisdom behind hiding adultery between spouses?

I know we aren't supposed to advertise our sins, but regarding hiding something as big as adultery, which is one of the biggest ways to desecrate the rights of the spouse, shouldn't the spouse have rights to know such things so they can make a decision to keep the marriage or divorce?

I am terrified that this can happen to me and I wouldn't have any knowledge of it. The adulterer would share a secret with my wife that I wouldn't know about, while I'm supposed to be the closest with my wife. Scary topic.

Comment: If you don't trust the person, you shouldn't consider marrying her.

Comment: You're right. We should marry people considering Taqwa. Thanks for the reply, I was looking for anything.

Answer (score -1):

Suspicion is not allowed in Islam, if you are follower; be steadfast.

In Sura [An Nur](https://quran.com/24) adulterers cannot marry Muslims and vice versa; it is an order from Allah (swt).

Search for others if you have doubts; you cannot live with doubts lifelong.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE.  I've noticed you're writing a lot of answers and they're not being particularly well received by the community.  There's some helpful advice at meta [How do I write a good answer to a question?](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/598).  In this case, it'd be beneficial to quote the Qur'an exactly, rather than the whole of Sura An Nur.